# Default option on a select form corresponds to current page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a select form like this:

```
echo "<option value='../profile'>Saves</option>";
echo "<option value='../notifications' selected='selected'>Notifications</option>";
echo "<option value='../settings'>Settings</option>";
```

How can I add the attribute `selected='selected'` to the option corresponding to the current page using jQuery?

Comment: you tagged jquery-ui? i don't see it anywhere in your question?

Comment: I'm using it to skin my select elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to use php.

```
$selected1 = ($_GET['page'] == 'profile') ? 'selected' : null;
$selected2 = ($_GET['page'] == 'notif') ? 'selected' : null;
$selected3 = ($_GET['page'] == 'settings') ? 'selected' : null;

echo '<option value="../profile" '.$selected1.'>Saves</option>';
echo '<option value="../notifications" '.$selected2.'>Notifications</option>';
echo '<option value="../settings" '.$selected3.'>Settings</option>';
```

To change according to the default page

Comment: I think a switch would be better and selected="selected" would make the code validate :)

Answer (score 0):

what server side scripting language are you using? I would guess php but thats the only one I'm familiar with. Why use jquery when you creating your page dynamically?

Comment: I just thought jQuery would be the easiest to use for this, and yes, I am using PHP.